# Howto query average of most recent data in sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to find the average of the most recent x results. Is it possible to use an aggregate function on a limited number of results with sql server?

Here is what I have tried and the errors I get:

```
select avg(top(100) convert(float, AnalysisData))
from tab
order by DatePerformed desc
```

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'top'.

```
select AVG(data)
from (
select top(100) convert(float, AnalysisData) As data
from tab
order by DatePerformed desc
);
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

This is sql server 2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example, you need an alias name for the subquery:

```
select AVG(data)
from (
    select top 100 convert(float, AnalysisData) As data
    from tab
    order by DatePerformed desc
) Top100Records;
```

You probably don't need the parenthesis around `100` either.